# preposition after an infinitive

Tags: prepositions

I'm familiar with this sentence

> He is a tough guy to deal with.

And I understand why there should be a with after to deal. My teacher used to say that you could un-shorten the infinitive to an attributive clause like

> He is a tough guy which you will deal with.

But this sentence is confusing to me,

> He has enough money to buy a racing car (with).

First, the infinitive can be unshortened to

> He has enough money with which he can buy a racing car.

But it could also be unshortened to

> He has enough money so that he can buy a racing car.

Does that mean I can use ....to buy a racing car and ...to buy a racing car with?

Comment: This is a rule with which I'm not quite familiar.

Comment: Parse it carefully.

Comment: Another teacher who hasn't gotten the news that the rule about not ending a sentence with a preposition is long gone and was never a good rule.  (Also consider "deal with" as a phrasal verb.)

Comment: Never end a sentence that begins with 'to' by 'for'. Any advance on ending a sentence with four prepositions ?

Comment: @NigelJ - What about a sentence that begins with "2x4"??

Comment: Xanne, Hot Licks is broadly correct, and IMHO his worst failing there was not to add *unless you’re sufficiently comfortable with the language that you can happily justify your choice.*

I think *He is a tough guy to deal with* is a fine example, and works far better than *He is a tough guy with whom to deal* but more usefully, *He has enough money to buy a racing car* is just fine by itself. 

The other examples have their own challenges to resolve, prolly somewhere such as https://ell.stackexchange.com/ before any of them is ready to do a job here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be on ELL but is too old to migrate.